# html marker add additional properties in azure maps

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-maps

I am loading all sites of companies as a html markers in azure maps and on click of it, launch a popup that displays site specific information.

The Html marker does not have any property bag, through which i can pass a bunch of site information that i can use in the popup that i intent to display on click of html marker.

azure maps documentation on HtmlMarker: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.htmlmarkeroptions?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple add a custom property to the html marker and add your data to that. That data will always be with the marker. For example:

```
var popup = new atlas.Popup();

//Create a HTML marker and add it to the map.
var marker = new atlas.HtmlMarker({
    position: [0, 0]
});

//Add your custom property with data
marker.properties = { 
    title: 'hello world'
};

map.markers.add(marker);

 map.events.add('click', marker, function(e){   
    //Get the clicked marker.                
    var m = e.target;

    //Get custom properties on the marker
    var p = m.properties;

     popup.setOptions({
        content: `<div style="padding:10px;">${p.title}</div>`,
        position:m.getOptions().position,
        pixelOffset: [0, -18]
    });

    //Open the popup.
    popup.open(map);                    
});
```